# Property 'hero' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial. But I'm getting this error and couldn't figure out how to fix it myself.

```
src/app/app.component.html:3:25 - error TS2339: Property 'hero' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

3 <div><span>Id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
                          ~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

app.component.html below

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div><span>Id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div><span>Name: </span>{{hero.name}}</div>
```

heroes.component.ts below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
   hero: Hero = {
     id: 1,
     name: 'Windstorm',
   }



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: The error message refers to `app.component.html` and `AppComponent` but `hero` is defined inside `HeroesComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to interpolate the property "**hero**" declared  in **HeroComponent** inside **app.component**. You can't do this. You can do the interpolation inside **AppComponent**, if you declare the proprerty inside **app.component.ts**. If you necessary need to declare hero inside HeroComponent and use it inside AppComponent, you need to use some strategy to comunicate between componets. You can do this with [@Input/@Output decorators](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs), or using a [Service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

Answering in case anyone else struggles with the tutorial.

If you want to import one component into another "just like that" it won't work. Something goes awry in the tutorial, I know that I did not have an app.module.ts when I created a new project (angular cli 17.0.5) so the line in the tutorial about how I could magically import my ****HeroesComponent**** is not applicable. Either way, to add a component to another you have to options. Either your component is a standalone, or you need to work with the ngModules, which is a part that they only cover later in the tutorial.

To be able to import your Heroes Component without ngModules, you need to add this in the @Component of your app.component.ts :

```
standalone: true,
```

Then also in the app.component.ts, you need to import your HeroesComponent at the top:

```
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
```

And further down your @Component should look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, HeroesComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
```

Edit to add: the latest version of the Angular CLI does now work with standalone components rather than ng modules. The Heroes tutorial as of December 2023 is still written for an angular app with ngmodules. See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52751